# Show that there exists a group of order $p^{3}$, with p prime.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am a bachelor student in mathematics and studying group theory at home I came across this exercise where there is need to show the existence of this group, because given any prime, is it possible to ensure that there is a group of order $p^{3}$ ?

Comment: There is always the cyclic group for any finite order.  Maybe you mean non-abelian group?

Comment: @user10354138 In the problem there were no conditions for the possible group of order $p^{3}$, but if the problem becomes more interesting if the group is not abelian, it would be fun to think imposing this condition.

Comment: If you know about the direct product, you can try to build such a group from groups of order $p$.

Comment: @JoshB. I didn't want to use group action to respond, but direct product would be a good one. How could I do it?